# Error when a shared pointer is pushed back into a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, shared-ptr

Look at the following snippet of code.

```
#typedef std::shared_ptr<node> node_ptr;
std::vector<node_ptr> temp;               
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)               
{ 
    temp.push_back(&m_nodes.at(n[i]-1)) // Got error in this line
}
```

`m_nodes` is defined as a vector of node objects.

```
std::vector<node> m_node;
```

When I evaluated this code, I got the following error:

```
 error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::shared_ptr<node> >::push_back(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<node> >::value_type*)'
                     temp.push_back(&m_nodes.at(n[i]-1));
                                                       ^
```

My knowledge about pointers is limited and I couldn't figure out the mistake. Please help

**EDIT**
From the answers given below and through a google search, I'm in a conclusion that vector of pointers is a bad idea. But in my case only necessity made me to use a vector of pointers. I'm using C++ for scientific computation and the node object contain variables which I need to calculate. Since number of node objects are large, it is difficult to copy and move every time. So, for passing into functions and initialization of other class object I need to use pointer to the node or reference.
If `shared_ptr` is a wrong choice in my context, is there any other simple efficient way to do this? Since I'm a beginner in C++ I would prefer a simple solution.

Comment: the unary operator `&` goes before the operand

Comment: @vu1p3n0x, Is it the above edit what you mentioned?

Comment: How have you learned C++? Why are you (ab)using a macro where a type alias is in order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`shared_ptr` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) that accepts a `Y*` is `explicit`. It won't participate as a user defined conversion to turn a raw pointer into a `shared_ptr`. And `temp.push_back` is not overloaded to accept a raw pointer. Hence your error.

You *could* make the compile-time error go away, but then your program will exhibit undefined behavior when the `shared_ptr`s in `temp` will start calling `delete` on objects owned by `m_nodes`.

---

And that use of a macro is horrendous. Use a type alias:

```
using node_ptr = std::shared_ptr<node>;
```

---

Since you seem to need non-owning pointers (`shared_ptr` is for complex ownership semantics). It's perfectly fine to pass around a vector of raw pointers. In your case, just make the type alias be this:

```
using node_ptr = node*;
```

That will change the semantics properly without rewriting your entire code.

Comment: Could you please give me a suggestion for above edit?

Answer (score 1):

You can't `push_back` a pointer into a vector of smart pointers, you should use `emplace_back()` instead to construct a shared pointer in-place:

```
// this will create a new shared_ptr in-place, and will call the appropriate constructor for it.
temp.emplace_back(&m_nodes.at(n[i]-1));
```

Also you should use a typedef instead of a macro:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<node> node_ptr;
// or, better yet:
using node_ptr = std::shared_ptr<node>
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked. But after successful compilation of the program, I'm getting the following error after output--` double free or corruption (!prev) ` . Is this error related to the above problem?

Comment: @user294664, you can't create a vector of nodes that are on the stack, and then just make smart pointers of their addresses, because they will be deleted twice.

Comment: Could you give a me suggestion then?